# how to use shift+tab on keepass auto type

Tags: password-management, keepass

I need to automate the login to an application that start with the cursor on the password.
I want to use `shift + tab` to move on the username before actually starting the password sequence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A special character can prepended to the key you want to invoke. In this case just `+{TAB}` is needed, here the complete example.

```
+{TAB}{CLEARFIELD}{UserName}{TAB}{CLEARFIELD}{Password}{ENTER}
```

Other key modifiers are:

- Ctrl: prepending `^`
- Alt: prepending `%`